# Difference between CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE and cvtCOLOR(..., BGR2GRAY)

Tags: c++, opencv

Can someone please tell me the difference between

```
imread("Picture", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
```

and

```
cvtCOLOR(input, output, BGR2GRAY);
```

Both these functions produce the same picture - which is a gray picture.
So, what's the difference between both?

Comment: First one reads it from a file and converts it. Second just converts an existing image. It should be fairly obvious, especially if you read the documentation.

Comment: They might produce slightly different grayscale images, because the first one utilizes codecs, and the second one just converts it using the formula described in the documentation. See [opencv docs](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/12705/commits/df4139d37350619ab25ef51a68bb60d4e325afe2)